# jQuery CSS put image over image turns into strobe light

Tags: jquery, css

I have an image gallery.

There is a list of thumbs.  When you hover over an image, a red x appears that allows you to delete that image.

My problem is, the x blinks when you hover on it.  I am assuming that it sees as when the x div appears, it thinks it is a mouseout event so hides it.

Is there a better way to do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/guyfromfl/7ZNGY/1/

The x lines up correctly on my layout, not in jsfiddle, but its not that big of a deal to try to fix...

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder...can you not see it?  If not I'll post it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without modifying your HTML structure, you need to use `mouseenter` `mouseleave` events like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/7ZNGY/3/

`mouseout` considers only the target of your binding element, so if you hover something inside the container it will count as a "mouseout", while `mouseleave` understands that only leaving the container is counted as a "mouseout"

So when you hovered over the X button, it counted as a "mouseout" which hides the element, and you are now in the plain container which triggers `mouseover`, and this loop causes the strobo effect

**edit** code:

```
$(document).delegate('.preview_image', 'mouseenter mouseleave', function (event) {
    var eId = $(this).find("img").get(1).id;
    var id = eId.replace("preview_", "");
    if (event.type == 'mouseenter') {
        $('#delete_img_' + id).fadeIn(100);
    } else {
        $('#delete_img_' + id).fadeOut(100);
    }
});
$(document).delegate('.delete_container', 'click', function () {
    alert("You dirty rat");
});
```

Comment: Sorry about the delay had to take care of something... but thats it. thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle is incomplete, but I imagine you are binding to the hover over the `img` element. Instead, place the image inside another container that will capture the click event. The red x should also be part of this container. That way even when the red x is positioned on the image it won't steal the focus and remove your hover.

```
<span class="imgcontainer">
  <img src="" />
  <img src="redx" position:absolute; top: 0; right: 0; />
</span>

$('imgcontainer').hover()...
```

Comment: what is missing? it is running fine on mine?

Comment: @guyfromfl - it was missing the js originally. The user added it after the question was posted.

Comment: yea i realized it, then updated to /1/ after i caught it...i was hoping i caught it fast enough but you guys are too quick lol

Comment: @mrtsherman, the only difference in what you are saying and what I have is using a span not div, and put the pic first.  I am using the delegate function instead of hover.

Comment: i retract that..i see what you're getting at. sorry